# Greyed out code in VS Code with the C/C++ and TypeLens extensions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

i'm trying to solve the following issue with VS Code and the C/C++ Extension from Microsoft.

The mentioned Extension adds a reference count above every function/object definition in the source code. That's a helpful feature so far, but for me it doesn't work as intended I think.

In my example I started implementing a thread-safe linked list to practice (please ignore the code, thats not what this topic is about). The whole class is greyed out although I import the header-file and instantiate an object of that class in the main.cpp file in the main-function. Also, the whole main function is greyed out because no references to the main-function are found. That makes no sense to me, why would I ever reference the main-function in my code? It's the entry point to the program and shouldn't be referenced in my project source code afaik.

When I disable the C/C++ Extension, the reference counts are gone and the source code is highlighted again. But I would really like to keep the reference count and only get rid of the greyed out code (or make it work properly so that main function and definitions I reference in my code are not greyed out).

Also by disabling the extension, code auto completion is gone. So that's not a good trade.
I spent hours of reading the configuration and searching the web for solutions, but I couldn't find anything helpful.
The only thing slightly realted to the greying out of code I found is the option "Dim inactive regions" found in the C/C++ Extension's setting. But it didn' solve my problem.

Thank you in advance for reading/trying to help!

Example of greyed out code and reference count:

[image: Example of greyed out code and reference count]

greyed out main function because of 0 references to main:

[image: greyed out main function because of 0 references to main]

Dim inactive code option:

[image: Dim inactive code option]

Update:
So it turned out that the reference counter not only disappears when I disable the C/C++ extension but also when I disable the TypeLens extension. That does not solve my problem but at least I can get rid of the greyed out code by disabling TypeLens and still use the auto completion the C++ extension provides.

Comment: maybe disable `semantic highlighting`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I set semantic highlighting to false, restarted vs code, but unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried unchecking the "Dim Unactive Regions" under the C/C++ Extension Settings?

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately that doesn't work (see last screenshot in my post). Thank you for answering.

Comment: The template class is referenced in `main()` so you need to solve the problem with `main()` first. Some possible issues to check: Is the file included in the project? It it a C/C++ project? Is your function the only `main()` declared within the project? Does it still appear unreferenced if you delete the class declaration?

Comment: A useful technique of narrowing the problem down is described in [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Same approach may be useful in your case, too.

Comment: With which tool do you build the cpp file?

Comment: @ALX23z I use cmake 3.16.3 as build tool, GCC 9.3.0 as compiler.

Comment: @CiaPan thanks for your input. I checked everything you mentioned. The files are included in my project. There is only the main function I showed in one of the screenshots. And it's still unreferenced when I comment the class declaration. Also the main function is unreferenced and greyed out when I write a simple hello world program. So I think the code I wrote has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Possibly the VC extension you use is not aware of specific features of C/C++, like '_the `main()` function is referenced; always._' I think I would look for an option in configuration to tell it so.

Comment: FTR, that dimming feature is flaky. E.g. it dims lines here that are simple line-end comments... While not dimming a preceding/following line that's another comment, just like the one dimmed. And also some function definitions, which are in use, and are just like any others. After some copy-pasting to move things around the dimming disappeared. But the lightbulb still pops up for those lines, offering to disable inactive r. col. Weird. Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the updated question, the problem isn't realted to the C/C++ Extension. It is acutally the TypeLens extension that causes problems here.

The best solution I have found is to configure TypeLens to not grey out unreferenced code. This way I can keep the reference counter and the code completion feature from the C/C++ extension but prevent the source code from being greyed out by TypeLens.

To achieve this, you have to set the Typelens:Unusedcolor value from #999 to nothing (just delete the value).

Comment: I will accept this answer as solution to my problem in 2 days as I am not yet allowed to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly you should declare your main function with

```
 int main(void)
```

or

```
 int main(int argc, char * argv [])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I tried both variants but unfortunately that does not solve the 0 reference problem. It's still greyed out.